# Is is possible to convert from string to int in iOS?

Tags: ios, nsstring

I want to convert from string to int.

Here is my code:

```
NSString *a = @"hello";
NSInteger b = [a integerValue];
NSLog(@"String to INT =--------> %d",b);
```

but the result always like this:

```
String to INT =--------> 0
```

Comment: You should read https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSString/integerValue

Comment: What were you expecting?  Are you sure you don't want to count the number of characters in the string instead?

Comment: For example @"a" --> 97

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so you want the numeric value for each character in the string:

```
NSString *a = @"hello";
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [a length]; i++) {
    unichar c = [a characterAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"Character %u = %u", i, (unsigned)c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically firing `integerValue` message on a string converts the numeric values in string format to the format suggested by message(integerValue).

And you should use this if your string contains numeric values and you need to extract them in primitive format.

Answer (score 0):

it will help to convert from string to int in ios

- NSString* val = @"12";
  [NSNumber numberWithInt:[val intValue]]